# Loop to subtract columns of different data frames to normalize data

Tags: r, loops, frame

I need to subtract time zero absorbance column from four other data frames to normalize data. Ideally this will be done by a loop that goes through each data frame and subtracts each absorbance column from the original time zero absorbance creating a 4 new normalized data frames. I have a lot of data so a loop is the only feasible option. To give you an idea A data frame looks like:

well ID, Absorbance value

Comment: It would be easier to help if you create a small reproducible example along with expected output. Read about [how to give a reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is overall a bad idea to keep data of corresponding measurements within different `data.frames`. You should really consider putting all those measurements into one `data.frame` and then your task will become almost trivial. Please consider `cbind`ing or `merge`ing your `data.frames`.

Ok, back to the original question. Optimally you'd have all of the `data.frames` you want to loop over in a `list` as in

```
expl <- list(
  one.hour = data.frame(id = 1:10, absorbance = runif(10)),
  two.hours = data.frame(id = 1:10, absorbance = runif(10)),
  three.hours = data.frame(id = 1:10, absorbance = runif(10))
)

zero.absorbance <- data.frame(id = 1:10, absorbance = runif(10))
```

Then you can loop over the elements of that list e.g., with a `for` loop

```
for (i in 1:length(expl)){
  expl[[i]]$corrected.absorbance <- expl[[i]]$absorbance - zero.absorbance$absorbance
}
```

And peak at the results:

```
head(expl[[1]])  # first example data.frame
head(expl[[2]])  # second example data.frame
head(expl[[3]])  # third...
```

Comment: Thank you, I agree it is not optimal to have separate data frames. How would I go about normalizing the data in a loop if each data frame was combined into one?

Comment: A loop is not necessary to compute a new data frame column as a function of other columns.